# Manga where a girl dies every time a boy falls in love with her

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm searching for a manga that I can't remember the name of (I read it around 2015). The drawing style was clearly not shojo.

- A boy who is the narrator (7-8 years old, white) meets a girl (7-8 years old too, I think she was blonde) and falls in love with her, but, a few days later she dies.
- Then, time passes (1-2 years) and he meets a new girl exactly like her (just the hairstyle changed a little and she had grown too). He falls in love a second time and she dies.
- Then, we see that the time passes (like ten years) and he meets the girl many times, and every time he can't resist, falls in love, and she dies. This scene was memorable because we see few page where this happened on loop (meet, love, death). Each time the girl is slightly different (one time she is the president of the school, another she is in a club, ect)
- Finally... I don't know. We arrived at a time where they are 18 years old (or 21, idk). And I can't remember what happened. I would say that the boy was smaller than the girl.

So, I don't remember if it's a one shot or a real manga but it has a greater chance to be a one shot. I don't think it's a hentai. But I can't find it.

Comment: Please visit https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question and see if that helps elicit more details.

Comment: Incidentally, if someone does post the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark as per the [tour].

Comment: While you mentioned the boy was white and the girl was blonde, can you remember if the setting is in Japan/"foreign" country? How about the drawing style, is it like a typical shonen, shojo, or seinen style? By "finally", did you mean the story ends in that way? And do you remember at the very least around what year you read it?

Comment: It was a slice of life in japan. The massive part of what I remember happen in the school.
I don't remember very well of the drawing style. It was not like a shojo for sure. More like a Shonen.
And the finally means I don't remember what happen after. I am almost sure that when they have 18 or 21 years, the scene with the loop of death stop, and the time begin like a slice of life normal. But I can't tell what happen next. It can be a one shot and stop here. It can be the start of the manga and continue (and I don't remember read the sequel). Or, It can be a manga which start and dont finish

Answer (score 1):

It might be Fujimi Lovers. The boy falls in love with a girl but she keeps dying everytime she realizes her feelings.